# I tought a matrix that can be row reduced to the identity matrix is also invertible.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

This matrix i can convert the identity matrix. $\begin{bmatrix}
1 &2  &-1   \\ 
-1 &0  &3   \\ 
0 &1  &1   
\end{bmatrix}.$

see here:

[image] --> [image]

still, the determinant is 0 of the first matrix.
I thought if a matrix has 3 pivot points then it is invertible?

Was my tought wrong or is there something wrong with this matrix? I thought it was a theorem that if a matrix has n pivot points it is automatically invertible

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error lies in the assumption that the determinant is $0$. Actually, it is equal to $-2$.

Comment: sorry, i made a notation error. I changed the right upper 1 of the matrix to a -1. Now the determinant is  0. Okay and now everything makes sens. Stupid. I will remove this question